# Touchpad - Have to wait for the left click to work

Tags: touchpad

I have a touchpad that worked right away after I installed Debian, but recently I've had a problem: If I try to select text, I have to stop moving my finger on the pad for one second of so after pressing the left click before starting to move again to actually select what I want. But that's not the strangest part of it. I have a second set of "mouse buttons" just above and the left button of the set works normally... It can't be that the computer needs some time so understand that the button got clicked because for simple clicks (not click and hold), it works instantly. Which means somewhere, in a configuration file, something tells gnome 3 or whatever gets the input that it should wait 1s before considering a "click and hold" as a "click and hold". Would someone know where this could be and how to fix it?

I went through [this](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html) but I couldn't find anything that looked like it could help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue after a recent update and if Debian had an update history I would find which update did it and revert it back to the old one as the computer is almost unusable as it is now.

Comment: Maybe you could research how to do this and add it to your answer?

Comment: I did find out there is a history stored for a short time under /var/log/history and it looks to have been an update to X11 that caused the issue. While trying to find which one to revert I did another update and the issue has gone away. So my suggestion right now is try another update and if not have a look at X11 updates from the week of May 27th